# How to change core pattern only for a particular application?

Tags: linux, unix, coredump

My application requires the core dump file to be generated in a specific pattern. I want the core file generated with file name in a given format (which contains PID of the process, etc). This can be done by setting the pattern in /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern. using specifiers like %p, %e. But this method will affect the core file pattern globally. I don't want this to happen. I'm not allowed to change the core pattern of other processes and others' processes.

How do I do this without affecting other processes?

And how do I do this when /proc is read-only?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`man core` tells us:

> Piping core dumps to a program
>
> Since kernel 2.6.19, Linux supports an alternate syntax for the
>        `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` file.  If the first character of this
>        file is a pipe symbol (`|`), then the remainder of the line is
>        interpreted as a program to be executed.  Instead of being written to
>        a disk file, the core dump is given as standard input to the program.
>
> Note the following points:
>
> - The program must be specified using an absolute pathname (or a
>           pathname relative to the root directory, /), and must immediately
>           follow the '|' character.
> - The process created to run the program runs as user and group
>           root.
> - Command-line arguments can be supplied to the program (since Linux
>           2.6.24), delimited by white space (up to a total line length of
>           128 bytes).
> - The command-line arguments can include any of the % specifiers
>           listed above.  For example, to pass the PID of the process that is
>           being dumped, specify %p in an argument.

You can put a script there, like e.g.

```
| /path/to/myscript %p %s %c
```

You can detect which process is triggering the coredump: (`man core`):

```
       %%  a single % character
       %p  PID of dumped process
       %u  (numeric) real UID of dumped process
       %g  (numeric) real GID of dumped process
       %s  number of signal causing dump
       %t  time of dump, expressed as seconds since the Epoch,  1970-01-01
           00:00:00 +0000 (UTC)
       %h  hostname (same as nodename returned by uname(2))
       %e  executable filename (without path prefix)
       %E  pathname of executable, with slashes ('/') replaced by exclama‐
           tion marks ('!').
       %c  core file size soft resource limit of crashing  process  (since
           Linux 2.6.24)
```

Now all you have to do is "do the default thing" for other processes than your own

Comment: @t_thirupathi well. My point is you can make a script that does the default thing except for your own programs. Don't "false-thank" me if you didn't understand the answer.

Comment: I'm sorry for misunderstanding. I like the answer. Gonna try it out. 
I have few questions though. 


1. Will it be applicable for the child processes and threads (LWPs) created by the application?


2. Is there a shortcut to list multiple applications with same core pattern?


3. Is it mandatory that the process be run as root? My process needs to be run as a different user.


Thanks.

Comment: 1. You can implement most any logic you wish in your script (use `ps` to find parent process/process groups, eg.). 2. Same for "listing" applications (a simple bash script would use `case...esac` with glob patterns) 3. No. The script will (obviously) be run a root. You can drop privileges (sudo -u otheruser e.g.)