# Is it possible to add the SHA of my current commit to the core file pattern?

Tags: linux, git, coredump

I'm looking to add the git sha to the core file pattern so I know exactly which commit was used to generate the core file. 
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what you mean by "the core file pattern".  (In particular, when a process crashes and the Linux kernel generates a core dump, it uses `kernel.core_pattern`.  This setting is system-wide, not per-process.  There is a way to run an auxiliary program—see [How to change core pattern only for a particular application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637720/how-to-change-core-pattern-only-for-a-particular-application)—but that only gets you so far; you still have to write that program.  See also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport.)  But there is a general problem here, which has some hacky solutions, all of which are variants on a pretty obvious method that is still a little bit clever.

#### The general problem

The hash of the commit you are about to make is not known until after you have made it.  Worse, even if you can compute the hash of the commit you are about to make—which you can, it's just difficult—if you then *change the content* of some committed file that will go into the commit, so as to include this hash, you *change the content of the commit you do make* which means that you get a different actual commit hash.

In short, it is impossible to commit the commit hash of the commit inside the commit.

#### The hacky solution

The general idea is to write an untracked file that you use in your build process, so that the binary *contains* the commit hash somewhere easily found.  For projects built with Make, see [how to include git commit-number into a c++ executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6526451/1256452) for some methods.

The same kind of approach can be used when building tarballs.  Git has the ability to embed the hash ID of a *file* (blob object) inside a work-tree file, using the *ident* filter, but this is the ID of the *file*, which is usually not useful.  So, instead, if you use `git archive` to produce tar or zip files, you can use `export-subst`, as described in [the gitattributes documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) and referred-to in [the `git archive` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html).  Note that the tar or zip archive also holds the commit hash ID directly.

Last, you can write your own custom smudge filter that embeds a commit hash ID into a work-tree file.  This might be useful in languages where there is no equivalent of an external *make* process run to produce the binary.  The problem here is that when the smudge filter reads `HEAD`, it's set to the value *before* the `git checkout` finishes, rather than the value *after* it finishes.  This makes it much too difficult to extract the correct commit hash ID (if there is even a correct one—note that `git describe` will append `-dirty` if directed, to indicate that the work-tree does not match the `HEAD` commit, when appropriate).